# What are Honarary Editors?

Tags: journals, editors

As in the title: what is the function of an Honorary Editor on a journal's editorial board, as opposed to regular editors?

I have seen this a few times in a journal and I suspect it is supposed to add legitimacy to a journal, in particular if the journal only recently started being published. But what is their official function?

Answer (score 3):

The official function will be what is negotiated between the journal and the honorary editor. It could be anything from nothing to being a full editor.

Answer (score 0):

As Maarten says, the official function could be almost anything.

I've seen this title used to mean "a former editor who was really awesome" but I think it could also mean "someone who is doing some editing for us, pro bono" or "someone we ask for help when we have a tricky decision".